# Gaming on laptop with charger in

Tags: laptop, battery, gaming

As Im sure most already know, gaming laptops don't tend to have long battery lives.

To circumvent that, I'd just assume that I could game on the laptop while the charger's plugged in. 

However, my question is, is this okay to do ?
Batteries themselves have actual lifespans in years,

so I want to know if doing this will be detrimental to the laptop's battery or any of it's components

Thanks for any help in advanced.

Comment: Is the battery NiCad, NiMH, or Lithium?  That makes a difference in the charging pattern that will give it the longest life.  However, you can always remove the battery when it's charged and run on just the charger.

Comment: Hi, If your battery charge on your laptop shows as full charged then in that case you can go ahead and unplug the charger from your laptop in order to increase your laptop battery life, it is always recommended and you can save the battery power by making power adjustments in "Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Power Options".

Comment: I would be surprised if a laptop battery was NiCad these days, and @vembutech could you cite your source, or at least let us know what battery type this applies to?

Comment: @Tyson - Not everyone owns a new laptop. :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 removing the battery from this laptop isn't a particularly easy feat. But thanks for the input nonetheless.

Comment: @vembutech I do plan to keep the laptop on power saver mode when I'm using it lightly, ex web browsing, coding, etc

Comment: See my comment on davidgo's answer.  Leaving it in and using it is better than removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, doing this is detrimental to the battery life, but only very mildly so - i'd probably do it anyway as things are for using - and it won't kill your battery suddenly or in an unreasonable timeframe.

The reason it is detrimental is 2 parts:

1. Batteries [Lithium based ] are best kept at 40-80% charge - keeping them at 100% charge
   is not as good for them - so while it will decrease the lifespan it won't do so
   dramatically - especially if you are planning on getting a new one in a couple of years
   (or hell, just budget to replace the battery)
2. I'm guessing that the gaming you are doing is going to create significant heat for the
   components - including the battery - this will shorten the life as well.

That said, and I can't stress this enough - its not like it will kill the battery in a couple of months - its just "not as good" as not doing it - I'd still suggest leaving the battery in over taking it out (it helps with the power regulation for the laptop).

Comment: The best advice might be to leave the battery in and remove the charger.  Batteries have a finite number of charge cycles, but it's a big number.  Exercising the battery is probably better for it than keeping it fully charged all the time.

Comment: My laptop's battery is really weak. It can keep my computer for just 2 hours! so I myself decided to connecting it to charger all the time so if your laptop is like mine, dont pay much attention to the battery.

Comment: Thank you @davidgo. I appreciate the information and it really helped.